# Docker system prune: reclaimed 64G did not go back to file system

Tags: docker, gradle

Docker system prune: reclaimed 64G did not go back to file system.

```
> docker system prune
Total reclaimed space: 43GB

> dir
8 Dir(s)      0 bytes free
```

On windows 11, the C drive has 120G capacity. Running docker and gradle, no space left. Could not run build any more.

How to make the reclaimed back to file system?
How to use other drive(e.g. D) for docker cache/images?

Comment: Running Docker _on Windows_ means you've got an extra indirection layer: You need to worry not just about freeing up space on the Linux VM's filesystem, but also releasing that space to the Windows host. Run Docker natively on Linux, or on a VM you control instead of one created and managed under-the-hood by "Docker for Windows" infrastructure, and this is all moot (in the former case) or under your explicit control (in the latter).

Comment: BTW, I don't see how this is a gradle question. Knowing gradle doesn't contribute in any significant way to knowing how to get Docker for Windows to release space to the host (if it's even a feature that exists / has been implemented in the first place). Indeed, I'd argue that it isn't even a programming question at all; it's not about writing Dockerfiles, but about system administration.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy is there a way to release space from WSL to windows? my computer became unusable.

Comment: I'm absolutely the wrong person to ask about that. That said, _is_ Docker for Windows using WSL now? Earlier versions of WSL didn't support the requisite kernel features, so you needed a real Linux kernel running in a VM.

Comment: ...egh; that's unfortunate. Per https://marcroussy.com/2020/12/01/cleaning-up-docker-disk-space-in-wsl2/ and https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/244, it looks like even with WSL2 you still have a container with a virtual drive, so space won't make it back to the host even when it's free'd within that filesystem until the individual blocks are freed. There are references in that ticket to tools/processes for that purpose, though.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy The links helped to resolve this issue. thanks.